# Integrating facebook in android application should we need to follow any permissions to put the app in play store?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I integrated facebook in my application to post the emergency information on wall.I followed every step of integrating facebook.Now do u i need to follow any permissions from facebook to put my application in playstore.It should work for any facebook user to login through my application.Please help me through this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Facebook SDK and the proper APIs to login and post on Facebook there should not be any problem. Of course you need the proper key hash for the Facebook SDK which is compatile with your release version of the App (not with the debug key).

Apart from that I am not aware of any special permissions you would have to follow when you publish your App on Google Play.

Comment: Its working fine for just my login,but it does not work for any other users of the facebook.(The user has not authorized this application to perform the action)it shows this error for other user login..

Answer (score 0):

Done R&D and got a solution to my own question.

When approaching the facebook,other than default permissions we need to submit our application for review to facebook team in fb developer site.Then once approved we get the official permissions from facebook as we can do whatever we need to do through integration of facebbok..